# mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Tags: php, sql

Estoy haciendo un CRUD (web con formulario de CREAR, MOSTRAR, ACTUALIZAR y BORRAR), per me sale un error que no localizo su origen. ¿Qué será?

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/crud/formulario.php on line 64

[image: Da el siguiente error]

[image: Parte del código es éste y da error en la fila 64...]

Comment: Por alguna razón, la ejecución de tu `mysqli_query` genera un error en la BBDD, y en vez de devolver un `mysqli_result` devuelve `false`. Puedes verificar el error haciendo: `$ejecutar = mysqli_query( $con , $consulta ) or die ('Unable to execute query. '. mysqli_error($con));`

Comment: Ya está era simplemente un error de los datos de conexión. ¡Solucionado!